# Angular Chain Many Requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-promise, angular-http

I'm trying to build a service that can take CSV data, convert it to rows, and then make an API request for/from each row, adding the formatted results to an output string.

In other words, my (Coffeescript) code looks like this:

```
  $s.batchFetch = ->
    return unless $s.csv
    $s.output = ''
    for row in $s.csv.split("\n")
      $s._addToOutput(row)
```

The `$s._addToOutput()` function correctly makes an API call using the row, formats it, and adds the formatted response to my output string (`$s.output`). Basically, something like this:

```
$s._addToOutput (row) = -> 
  formattedResponse = ''
  $http.get("api/request/path/row-specific-whatever")
    .success (res) ->
      formattedResponse = $s._format(res)
    .then ->
      $s.output += formattedResponse
```

The **problem** is that the order of the formatted responses in my output string seems random/variable. It looks like the API takes faster/longer for certain rows than others, and whichever response comes back first gets added first -- with no respect for the order of my `rows` variable.

I figure the solution is some sort of Angular promise chaining, a la:

```
$s._addToOutput(row).then ->
  $s._addToOutput(secondRow).then ->
    $s._addToOutput(thirdRow).then ->
      ...
```

But I have an unpredictable number of rows coming in, and I'd love to be able to essentially just say: "Make the API calls for each row, **one after the other**."

Can anyone think of a good way to do this? I may just not be thinking straight right now, but I'm stumped.

Thanks!

Sasha

**EDIT** -- Gave ryeballar's solution a shot, but my implemenation of it is not actually stopping the reordering problem. Pretty sure it's a mistake on my end, so if anyone spots anything, please let me know:

(Note, I had to adapt the solution, because I make two consecutive requests for each row -- the first for the "venue" and the second for the "photo" of the venue I find. Also, `yamlify` == 'format'.)

```
$s.batchFetch = function() {
  if (!$s.csv) {
    return;
  }
  $s.output = '';
  return $scope.csv.split("\n").reduce(function(promise, row) {
    var rowPromise, split;
    split = row.split(',');
    rowPromise = $s._getVenue(split[0], split[1]).success(function(res) {
      var venue;
      venue = res.response.groups[0].items[0].venue;
      $s._getPhoto(venue).success(function(resp) {
        var photo;
        photo = $s._photoUrl(resp);
        return $s.output += $s._yamlify(venue, row, photo);
      });
    });
    return promise.then(rowPromise);
  }, $q.when());
};
```

Note -- `getVenue()` and `getPhoto()` are just calls to `$http`, so they return objects that respond to `success`, `error`, `then`, etc. `photoUrl()` is just a helper function for parsing the response object into a new API path.

**Latest effort**, which is still reordering randomly -- yes `_getVenue` and `_getPhoto` are just `$http.get(path)` calls:

```
$s.batchFetch = function() {
  if (!$s.csv) {
    return;
  }
  $s.output = '';
  return $s.csv.split("\n").reduce(function(promise, row) {
    var rowPromise, split;
    split = row.split(',');
    rowPromise = $s._getVenue(split[0], split[1]).success(function(res) {
      var venue;
      venue = res.response.groups[0].items[0].venue;
      return $s._getPhoto(venue).success(function(resp) {
        var photo;
        photo = $s._photoUrl(resp);
        return $s.output += $s._yamlify(venue, row, photo);
      });
    });
    return promise.then(rowPromise);
  }, $q.when());
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` by invoking each promise from one to the next. The initial value is a promise that will resolve immediately `$q.when()` and then invoke `rowPromise` which is also a promise, which creates a chaining effect whenever each `then()`s is invoked.

```
.controller('CsvController', function($scope, $q) {

  $scope.csv = '.....';
  $scope._format = function() {/*...*/};

  $scope.batchFetch = function() {
    $scope.output = '';
    return $scope.csv.split('\n').reduce(function(promise, row) {
       return promise.then(function() {
          return $http.get("api/request/path/row-specific-whatever", {row: row})
                          .success(function(res) {
                             $scope.output += $scope._format(res);
                          });
       });
    }, $q.when());
  };

});
```

**UPDATE:**
I have updated the code above, it should have been a callback instead of invoking the `$http` request during the iteration process. So your code should be something like this:

```
$s.batchFetch = function() {
  if (!$s.csv) {
    return;
  }
  $s.output = '';
  return $s.csv.split("\n").reduce(function(promise, row) {
    return promise.then(function() {
       var split = row.split(',');
       return $s._getVenue(split[0], split[1]).success(function(res) {
         var venue = res.response.groups[0].items[0].venue;
         return $s._getPhoto(venue).success(function(resp) {
           var photo = $s._photoUrl(resp);
           return $s.output += $s._yamlify(venue, row, photo);
         });
       });
    });
  }, $q.when());
};
```

As I read through your code, it seems to be falling on to a callback hell. Alternatively, it would be better to structure it like this instead:

```
$s.batchFetch = function() {
  if (!$s.csv) {
    return;
  }
  $s.output = '';
  return $s.csv.split("\n").reduce(function(promise, row) {
    var split, venue, photo;
    return promise
       .then(function() {
          split = row.split(',');
          return $s._getVenue(split[0], split[1]);
       }).then(function(response) {
          venue = response.data.response.groups[0].items[0].venue;
          return $s._getPhoto(venue);
       }).then(function(response) {
          photo = $s._photoUrl(response.data);
          return $s.output += $s._yamlify(venue, row, photo);
       });
  }, $q.when());
};
```

Comment: That's fascinating. I tried adapting that to my specific contstraints (row each row, I have to make two API calls, because the second depends on the first) -- and all the API calls worked, **but they're still out of order.** I posted my new code above (in pure JS). I'd really appreciate it if you'd let me know if something jumps out at you as wrong. Confused as to why your very cool solution doesn't appear to be working in this case.

Comment: try returning `$s._getPhoto(venue).success()`. I assume that `$s._getPhoto()` and `$s._getVenue()` are `$http` request services?

Comment: Yup. They're both `$http` requests. My latest attempt is above. Think I understood what you meant, but it's still reordering (!).

Comment: Check my update, sorry I have updated the first implementation as it does not work the way it was intended to work, the `$http` should have been a callback instead of invoking it before the `promise.then()` callback.

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! (Just had to define `venue` above `return promise` so it was carried between the promises.) That's awesome. Thanks so much. I'm about to go to sleep, but I'mma pour over this tomorrow so I understand it better. A little shaky on Angular promises/Q/callbacks/asynchronicity, etc. Really appreciate the help.